# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space when starting hive

Tags: java, hadoop, hive

Im aware theres lots of questions about this but I am still having no luck. Ive tried making the HADOOP_HEAPSIZE variable larger in hive-env.sh.

I cant understand why there wouldnt be enough memory in the first place, all I am trying to do is start hive and I havent even created any tables yet, I have just finished setting up the metastore.

Heres my error:

```
Logging initialized using configuration in jar:file:/usr/local/apache-hive-2.1.1-bin/lib/hive-common-2.1.1.jar!/hive-log4j2.properties Async: true
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:591)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:531)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:226)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:366)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:558)
... 9 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1654)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3367)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3406)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3386)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3640)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1652)
... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readStringBody(TBinaryProtocol.java:379)
at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:230)
at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:77)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.recv_set_ugi(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:4118)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.api.ThriftHiveMetastore$Client.set_ugi(ThriftHiveMetastore.java:4104)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.open(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:494)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.HiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(HiveMetaStoreClient.java:285)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.<init>(SessionHiveMetaStoreClient.java:70)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.MetaStoreUtils.newInstance(MetaStoreUtils.java:1652)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.<init>(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:80)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:130)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.RetryingMetaStoreClient.getProxy(RetryingMetaStoreClient.java:101)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.createMetaStoreClient(Hive.java:3367)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3406)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getMSC(Hive.java:3386)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllFunctions(Hive.java:3640)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.reloadFunctions(Hive.java:236)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.registerAllFunctionsOnce(Hive.java:221)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.<init>(Hive.java:366)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.create(Hive.java:310)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getInternal(Hive.java:290)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.get(Hive.java:266)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.start(SessionState.java:558)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.session.SessionState.beginStart(SessionState.java:531)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.run(CliDriver.java:705)
at org.apache.hadoop.hive.cli.CliDriver.main(CliDriver.java:641)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: How much memory are you giving the JVM, often when people have this problem they say they have increased  the heap when actually they made it smaller. I would try 32 GB to start with if you have a machine that big.

Comment: Ive tried 32gb and still have the issue. I cant understand why the space is running out when all im trying to do is start the hive command line

Comment: Agreed, something must be corrupted in the state of your system as I can't imagine you need more than what ever memory it sets by default to start an unused hive.